# Change plot axis with bioinfokit

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bioinformatics

I have the following code which produces a volcano plot using Bioinfokit:

```
pip install bioinfokit

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bioinfokit
from bioinfokit import analys, visuz
import random

lg2f = [random.uniform(-5,10) for i in range(0,4000)]
pad = [random.uniform(0.0000001,0.999) for i in range(0,4000)]

df1 = {'log2FoldChange':lg2f, 'padj':pad}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

bioinfokit.visuz.GeneExpression.volcano(df=df1, lfc='log2FoldChange', pv='padj', lfc_thr=(1.5,1.5), sign_line=True,plotlegend=True, legendpos='upper right', legendanchor=(1.46,1), dotsize=0.1, gfont=7,xlm=(-5.0,10.0,1), pv_thr=(0.05,0.05))
```

The following plot is produced:

[image]

However, I am trying to find a way to extend the X-axis so that it ranges from -10  to 10. Currently the x-axis extends from -5 to 9.

Please let me know if you have ideas. I tried adding a "fake" data point in which to extend the axis but this does not really work very well.

Thanks

Comment: You're currently passing `xlm=(-5.0,10.0,1)` which tells bioinfokit to plot from -5 to 10 with intervals of 1. If you want -10 to 10, pass `xlm=(-10.0,10.0,1)` instead. If you want it to fit the data, don't pass the `xlm` parameter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import bioinfokit
from bioinfokit import analys, visuz
import random

lg2f = [random.uniform(-5,10) for i in range(0,4000)]
pad = [random.uniform(0.0000001,0.999) for i in range(0,4000)]

df1 = {'log2FoldChange':lg2f, 'padj':pad}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)

bioinfokit.visuz.GeneExpression.volcano(df=df1, lfc='log2FoldChange', pv='padj', lfc_thr=(1.5,1.5), sign_line=True,plotlegend=True, legendpos='upper right', legendanchor=(1.46,1), dotsize=0.1, gfont=7,xlm=(-10.0,10.0,1), pv_thr=(0.05,0.05))
```

[image]